# Does VMware Workstation 7 have a 64bit installer?

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I downloaded Workstation 7.0, build 203739 from vmware.com, which says it's for 32bit or 64bit operating systems.

When I installed it, it installed automatically to the `Program Files(x86)` folder of my Windows XPx64 system, and the task manager shows it as `vmware.exe(32)`.

So, my questions is, does the VMware Workstation program come in 64 bit version?

Answer (score 10):

There's only a single binary of VMware Workstation, which supports both 32 and 64-bit hosts (even though it gets installed in "Program Files (x86)" on Windows x64).

The **vmware.exe** process is just the front-end and it's always 32-bit, but the actual virtual machines (**vmware-vmx.exe**) are 64-bit on 64-bit hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The app itself is 32-bit but it supports 16, 32 and 64-bit VMs.

Answer (score 0):

While the VM software is 32 bit it supports 64 bit client OSs with 64bit virtual drivers for the virtualized hardware.

Answer (score 0):

it's correct. VMware workstation 7 only has a single installation for both 32bit and 64bit of windows. The management console program itself is a 32bit, but the virtual drivers will be installed the 64bit version on your Windows 64bit